# aws-sdk-mock validate service ctor call SNS

Tags: javascript, jestjs, aws-sdk-mock

I'm trying to validate that I supplied the correct arguments into the service ctor for SNS, but I don't know how to do it.

Now, I do know how to validate publish, but again, I'm trying to verify expectations for the SNS function/ctor.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
//code
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SNS = new AWS.SNS({bobby:'no'});

//test
const AWSmock = require('aws-sdk-mock');

describe('something', () => {
    beforeAll(()=>{
        AWSmock.mock('SNS','publish', Promise.resolve());
    });
    test('doing it', () => {
        const f = require('file');

        expect(AWSmock.SNS.calledWith({})).toEqual(true); //this example would be false, but I can't figure out how to reference the SNS method here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**From the documentation of `aws-sdk-mock` :**

> Project structures that don't include the `aws-sdk` at the top level node_modules project folder will not be properly mocked. An example of this would be installing the `aws-sdk` in a nested project directory. You can get around this by explicitly setting the path to a nested `aws-sdk` module using `setSDK()`.

```
//code
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SNS = new AWS.SNS({bobby:'no'});

//test
const AWSmock = require('aws-sdk-mock');
// setting the AWS explicitly might help
AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);

describe('something', () => {
    beforeAll(()=>{
        AWSmock.mock('SNS','publish', Promise.resolve());
    });
    test('doing it', () => {
        const f = require('file');

        expect(AWSmock.SNS.calledWith({})).toEqual(true); //this example would be false, but I can't figure out how to reference the SNS method here
    });
});
```